# C++ OpenGL texture coords VBO indexes changes between models

Tags: opengl, c++

I just load 3 models using assimp into my Engine and have some problems with textures. Through some research, I realized that texture coordinates VBOs indexes changes between models, according to this scheme:
At and of loading VBOs indexes of models is: 3 - first model, 6 - second model, 9 - third model, but the result:
[image: Result]

I tried to do this:

```
    GLint texCoordAttributeLocation = glGetAttribLocation(Scene_Objects[i].Shader_Index, "texCoord");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordAttributeLocation);
    if (i == 0) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9);
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3);
    }
    if (i == 2) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6);
    }
    glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordAttributeLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

And all textures showings right, why indexes changed to 9 - first model, 3 - second model, 6 - third model

[image: Right]

I load 4 models and found regularity of indexes changes, the index of first loaded and last loaded model are swapped